# List of Actors playing Chris Kelvin (Protagonist in 'Solaris' by Stanislaw Lem)

Tags: stanislaw-lem, actor-identification

Kindly provide a list with the names of Actors that have played Chris Kelvin from the book Solaris.
Please add the year in which the Movie in which the Actor played Chris Kelvin was produced.

Comment: What have you got so far? Didn't IMDB or Wikipedia have anything useful?

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0009253/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Kelvin (AKA Kris Kelvin) has been portrayed by 6 actors in three live-action films;

**Solaris (2002)**

- **George Clooney** (as Chris Kelvin)

**Solaris (AKA Solyaris) (1972)**

- **V. Statsinskiy** (as Kris Kelvin v yunosti)
- **Donatas Banionis** (as Kris Kelvin, psikholog)
- **Vladimir Zamanskiy** (as Kris Kelvin, psikholog)
- **Raimundas Banionis** (as Kris Kelvin v otrochestve)

**Solaris (AKA Solyaris) (1968) (Made-for-TV)**

- **Vasiliy Lanovoy** (as Kris Kelvon)

You can find a complete listing on IMDB [here](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0009253/)

---

The book has also been converted into a play and opera. The following actors have played the leading role:

- [Charles Church](http://www.dimitrydevdariani.co.uk/solaris.html)
- [Dietrich Henschel](http://www.boosey.com/cr/news/Detlev-Glanert-reviews-of-Solaris-premiere-in-Bregenz/100083)
- Roero Arneis
- Zlatko Slavenski
- [Ron Cook](http://www.denofgeek.com/dvd-bluray/7486/solaris-review)

Comment: It appears that Banionis is listed double. And unless he played as double I did not see anyone but Banionis play Chris Kelvin the 1972 Solaris, but at least I found another Actor playing him (in the 1968 TV Mr. Lanovoy.)

Comment: Banionis isn't double-listed. The elder Donatas Banionis was born in 1923, the younger Raimundas Banionis was born in 1957 (making him approximately 14 at the time of filming). They're two different people albeit presumably related.

Comment: Then the younger one must have been the boy that was running around in the first act of the movie. That would fit. And the description then possibly says Chris Kelvins Son (which is only guesswork as google doesnt recognize the word otrochestve, yunosti und psikholog, though I would say the last one means psychologist.)

Comment: yunosti seems to mean "young/adolescent", otrochestve is "adolescent (middle-teens)", psikholog is "psychologist"